# How to keep ProgressBar Indeterminate animating

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been learning about how this issue is confronted via Threads (`BackgroundWorker` and others) and how to keep the UI responsive. I've managed to do so but then I realized that is not what I want. What I need actually is just to display an animating `ProgressBar` while a long operation is performed. (I don't need/want to update the UI because in that operation I'm exporting all graphical representation and the plotter is updated constantly).

I have thought about a Dialog popping-up with the progress bar while the operation is being performed. The problem is that I get this exception:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it
```

There are plenty of questions about this and the answer is to use `Dispatcher`:

```
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => myOperation(), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

Here is what've done:

I'm using Modern UI, there is a Dialog called ModernDialog, it's just a fancy dialog:

```
  class DialogProgress
{
    public ModernDialog progressDlg = new ModernDialog();

    public DialogProgress()
    {
        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
        bar.IsIndeterminate = true;
        bar.Width = 150;
        StackPanel content = new StackPanel();
        content.Children.Add(bar);
        progresoDlg.Content = content ;

        //Thread paralel = new Thread(() => myOperation());
        //paralel.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        //paralel.Start();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => myOperation(), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
    }

    void myOperation()
    {
        progresoDlg.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

I know I'm mixing stuff there, there are Threads and Dispatcher, but I can't figure out how to use them.

Here is how I call this dialog:

```
public void MyLongMethod()
{
        DialogProgress progress = new DialogProgress();
}
```

If I use only Dispatcher, the dialog shows up and the bar is being animated but MyLongMethod is not working (it starts after closing the dialog).

If I use Threads I get the mentioned exception.

How can I solve this problem?

(P.D. using a dialog Is only a suggestion, I would be happy too if the progress bar is in the UI and I switch the visibility when the long method starts/ends)

Comment: Try using a `delegate`

Answer (score 2):

```
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(...);
```

This goes wrong because you used Invoke(), it will not return until the invoked method finished running.  Which will take a while, ShowDialog() is a blocking call that doesn't complete until the user closes the dialog.

The simple workaround is to use BeginInvoke() instead.

Comment: If I use BeginInvoke() I get this error. Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type 
How could I convert the original method to a delegate type?

Comment: Use BeginInvoke(new Action(() => stuff));

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but the dialog it's not in a separate thread and the progress bar is not being animated. Is there a way to "force" the dispatcher to be in a new thread?

Comment: It is not in a separate thread, it runs on the UI thread.  Which is why you can see the dialog and WPF doesn't bitch at you for getting it wrong.  I can't guess why the progress bar doesn't animate, your question has no hints whatsoever what you might do to get it to animate.  Using a BackgroundWorker and implementing the ProgressChanged event is the boilerplate solution.

Comment: @Sturm You still must create your own thread to run the long operation. The dispatcher can be called *from* that other thread in order to schedule an update on the UI thread.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `ModernDialog` is a WPF `Window`, the [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) method does not return until it's closed. [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) also doesn't return until the operation is called and returns. You need to either use [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx) instead of `ShowDialog`, or call it with [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx) instead of `Invoke`. I would use `Show`, because `ShowDialog` doesn't really make sense unless you are waiting for the user to respond by clicking a dialog button.

Comment: has it got anything to do with `ProgressBar` ?

Comment: @Kyle No, the fact that a progress bar is involved is irrelevant to the issue. Why was this downvoted?